# Function implicit parameters not any more so after passing it to a higher order function

Tags: scala, function, implicit, implicits

In Scala you can do things like:

```
def foo(implicit v: Int) = println(v);
def h(x: Int) = { implicit val i: Int = x; foo }

h(42)
> 42
```

`h` call gets `foo` reference as a closure.

It wouldn't be strange to try passing `foo` to `h` as a parameter:

```
def g(x: Int)(f: Int => Unit) = { implicit val i: Int = x; f }
```

But it wouldn't work:

```
g(1)(foo)
> error: could not find implicit value for parameter v: Int
```

What I think it's happening is that `foo` gets called as an evaluation of the actual parameter. **Is that right?**

When passed a function with a normal parameter list (not implicit), the function is not being evaluated:

```
def foo2(v: Int) = println("Foo2")
g(1)(foo2)
> Int => Unit = <function1>
```

This is an expected result and `foo2` evaluation is not tried as a evaluation of an actual parameter.

**Why is `foo` evaluated as an actual parameter when no implicit values are available to do so?**

Same occurs with assignation:

```
val fooref: Int => Unit = foo
> error: could not find implicit value for parameter v: Int
```

It is like since `Int => Unit` doesn't match with a function where the `Int` parameter is marked as implicit, the compiler discard it as a valid actual parameter and therefore tries to evaluate it. Not finding a declared implicit value to fulfill the call.

If that is the case, **what whould be the way of expressing the type of a function with implicit parameters?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, functions cannot have implicit parameters - only methods can.

In the expression `g(1)(foo)`, `foo` is converted from a *method* to a *function* (also known as eta-expansion). And [section 6.26.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-conversions) of the Scala Specification states that implicit arguments are applied *before* eta-expansion.

See this ticket: [implicit methods behave suboptimally when used non-implicitly](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3781)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `f` parameter to function `g` is `Function1[Int, Unit]`. `Function1[A, B]` is a trait with the single method `apply(a: A): B`, where the `a` is not implicit. Hence, you cannot create an instance of `Function1[Int, Unit]` from `foo` - it wouldn't have the right signature.