# Scala implicit keyword in anonymous function

Tags: scala, lambda, implicit, anonymous

What is the significance of 'implicit' in this code block? I have seen such code in a few places in my project. How should I be using it to leverage 'implicit'.

```
implicit val a: Int = 10
val decorate: Int => Int => String = x => implicit y => {
  "*" + x + y + "*"
}
println(decorate(5))
```

I expected it to print

```
*510*
```

but it only prints the partial function representation itself

```
playground.MyLearnings$$$Lambda$26/0x0000000800cb9f60@2cb4c3ab
```

Comment: how aboud `def decorate(x: Int)(implicit y: Int) = s"*$x$y*"`

Comment: this works, but why does not the above work?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716707/function-implicit-parameters-not-any-more-so-after-passing-it-to-a-higher-order